# select-sorting strings by its length in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, selection

I must write a code in C, that sort strings by its length with select sort algorithm. But sorting doesn't work and I have no idea why :))

```
char * cityofMiddleEarth[CITIES] = { "Havens of Sirion", "Esgaroth", 
"Tirion", "Rivendell", "Romenna", "Hobbiton", "Carn Dum", 
                                     "Ephel Brandir", "Eldalonde", 
"Avallone", "Hyarastorni", "Linhir", "Minas Morgul", "Valmar", 
                                     "Waymeet", "Pelargir", "Obel Halad", 
"Bree", "Havens of the Falas", "Goblin Town", "Almaida" };

    int len, min, i, j;
    len = sizeof(cityofMiddleEarth) / sizeof(cityofMiddleEarth[0]);

    for (i = 0; i<len - 1; i++)
    {
        min = i;
        for (j = i; j<len; j++)
        {
            if (cityofMiddleEarth[j]<cityofMiddleEarth[min])
            {
                min = j;
            }
        }

        char *temp = cityofMiddleEarth[i];
        cityofMiddleEarth[i] = cityofMiddleEarth[min];
        cityofMiddleEarth[min] = temp;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing pointers, not string length.  To sort by string length, change:

```
cityofMiddleEarth[j]<cityofMiddleEarth[min]
```

to:

```
strlen(cityofMiddleEarth[j]) < strlen(cityofMiddleEarth[min])
```